# Shell script to find the string and insert after 2 lines in xml

Tags: xml, sed

Am unable to get the exact output for a XML

```
<String="12345">
<Bin>
<Value1 />
<Value2 />
</Bin>
</String>
```

Here need to find `<String=12345>`, then insert a line after `<Bin>` something similar to below

```
<String="12345">
 <Bin>
 <ValueXxxx />
 <Value1 />
 <Value2 />
 </Bin>
 </String>
```

Thanks in advance for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I *don't* intend to encourage people to parse or edit structured data
as `xml`, the following would work for this specific case:

```
nl=$'\n'
nl="\\$nl"

sed '
:l
N
$!b l
s#\(<String="12345">\n[^\n]*\n\)#\1<ValueXxxx />'"$nl"'#
' input.xml
```

which yields:

```
<String="12345">
<Bin>
<ValueXxxx />
<Value1 />
<Value2 />
</Bin>
</String>
```

- At first it slurps all lines in pattern space to enable matching with multiple lines.
- the regex `<String="12345">\n[^\n]*\n\` matches with the specified
  line followed by an arbitrary line.
- Then the `s` command inserts the string `<ValueXxxx />` and a newline
  just after the matched lines.

Comment: BTW is your xml file generated on Windows?